# Python keyboard library not sending keypresses to external program

Tags: python, events, triggers, raspberry-pi, keyboard

I'm building a media player using a Raspberry Pi. My current goal is to configure a passive infrared motion detector to pause the music when it detects motion (so that I can pause and resume the music when I wave my hand in front of the player).

I've got the motion detector hooked up and configured to pull down GPIO Pin 17 whenever motion is detected. I'm using the basic Linux terminal music player `mplayer`, which will pause and resume  whatever its playing with the space bar is pressed.

Right now, it is not working. The LED indicator light on the motion sensor shows that it is registering motion events. Previous experiments show that I am correctly reading the events on GPIO 17. For some reason, `mplayer` isn't registering the commands from my python script as keypresses. Here is my code as it stands now (I know its not pretty, I'm just tinkering at the moment):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import keyboard

SENSOR_PIN = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.VCM)
GPIO.setup(SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def motion_detected_callback(channel):
    keyboard.send("space")

GPIO.add_event_detect(SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=motion_detected_callback, bouncetime=2000)

try:
    while True:
        sleep(0.01)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I have tried all the `keyboard` library functions that seemed appropriate -- `keyboard.write("space", delay=0)`, `keyboard.send("space")`, nor `keyboard.press("space")` worked. [EDIT: None of these worked for the scancode of the the spacebar either, e.g. `keyboard.send(39)`.]

I also tried several ways of invoking the script. Neither `sudo python3 pir_sensor_listener.py & mplayer music.mp3` Nor `sudo python3 pir_sensor_listener | mplayer music.mp3` worked.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Often, certain python modules only work on certain platforms. Unfortunately, it seems that the keyboard module is not working in myplayer. To fix this, you can try using other modules. You can use pyautogui ([pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) info and docs):

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.press('space') #presses space bar and immediately releases
pyautogui.keyDown('space') #holds space key down
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.keyUp('space') #releases space key after 5 seconds
```

and note that when pyautogui holds a key down, for some reason, it can't type continously (although it is still holding down the key), so you won't get a bunch of spaces in the shell when you run the code usually, but if you truly wanted that output, you could simply do `pyautogui.press('space', presses=n)` to press space n times.

You can also use pynput like this ([pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) info and docs):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.space) #presses space key, holds until release command
keyboard.release(Key.space) #releases the space key
```

And I'm sure that there is another module that would fit this if those other two don't work. I do know that pynput is great for interacting with other platforms, but I don't know if it will work for myplayer.